# How to group together tags in a headlines made by org-capture?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I use the following capture code for making notes.

```
(setq org-capture-templates '((
     "n"                                         ; key
     "Add a note to abc.org file "               ; description 
     entry                                       ; type
     (file+headline "p.abc.org" "logg")          ; target
     "* %^{Logg}  :NOTE: %(org-set-tags)  \n%?"  ; template
     :prepend t                                  ; properties
     :empty-lines 1                              ; propertiesc
     )))
```

The template line consists of two sources of tags to the note. (1) I want all notes to be tagged with ":NOTE:", therefor this tag is written directly into the target line. (2) in addition I want to chose tags from my tags list by means of the function `org-set-tags`.

If I chose the tag `:FAMILY:` from my tagg list, the note heading end up looking like this:

```
* Note about something :NOTE: :FAMILY:
```

In this case only :FAMILY: is behaving as a tag (shown in bold in the headline). How can I change the target line so that the heading line will look like this: ?

```
* Note about something :NOTE:FAMILY:
```

where the two tags are collected into the single group :NOTE:FAMILY: and both function as tags?

It does not help to remove the space between `:NOTE:` and `%(org-set-tags)` in the target file, because the org-set-tags function insert spaces befor entering the tags you chose from you tags list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-set-tags` won't recognize :NOTE: as a tag, because the heading doesn't exist yet. the following should do it:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      `(("n"
         "Add a note to abc.org file "
         entry
         (file+headline "p.abc.org" "logg")
         ,(concat "* %^{Logg} "
                  "%(flet ((org-get-tags-string () \":NOTE:\")) (org-set-tags))"
                  " :NOTE:\n%?")
         :prepend t
         :empty-lines 1
         )))
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting, I will check it out as soon as possible :)

Comment: Your solution works great, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `%(org-set-tags)` in the template, use `%^g`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately your solution has exactly the same result as when using `%(org-set-tags). The "NOTE" tag is separated from the tags inserted by the `%^g` mechanism. If it works on your emacs, but not on my, what could cause such differences?

Comment: What version of org are you using?

Comment: I have version 8.2.10

Comment: It seems to work on 8.3.1

Comment: is there a simple way of upgrading?

Comment: Use the [repository](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html).  If you have problems, it's probably better to post a new question.